# Error while installing icecat Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: compiling, 19.04, icecat

Seems like everything I do requires extra steps. Here's where the install process gets. I've installed>updated>upgraded rustc and now I'm here.

```
0:02.95 checking for rustc... /usr/bin/rustc
0:02.95 checking for cargo... /usr/bin/cargo
0:03.03 checking rustc version... 1.34.1
0:03.05 checking cargo version... 1.34.0
0:03.36 ERROR: *** The pkg-config script could not be found. Make sure it is
0:03.36 *** in your path, or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable
0:03.36 *** to the full path to pkg-config.
0:03.42 *** Fix above errors and then restart with\
0:03.42                "/usr/bin/make -f client.mk build"
0:03.42 make[1]: *** [client.mk:150: configure] Error 1
make: *** [GNUmakefile:9: build] Error 2
```

What do now? 
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not installed?

```
sudo apt install pkg-config
```

Comment: thank you btw I was reading it as "The package you are installing script cannot be found" not The 'pkg-install' program cannot be found. all is good now.